# Replace a list slice with a packed tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples, slice

I have a list of points in the form of tuples:

```
myList = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5)]
```

I want to replace a slice of variable length with a new tuple `(6,6)` so the result is something like:

```
myList = [(1,1), (6,6), (5,5)]
```

I tried assigning the tuple to the slice, but this unpacks the tuple.

```
startIndex = 1
endIndex = 3
newTuple = (6,6)
myList[startIndex:endIndex] = newTuple
#myList == [(1, 1), 6, 6, (4, 4), (5, 5)]
```

My current method is below, but I was wondering if there was a way around this automatic unpacking and if there were any better or more readable ways to do this.

```
myList[startIndex] = newTuple
del myList[startIndex+1:endIndex]
```

Comment: How about `myList[startIndex:endIndex] = [newTuple]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your tuple (which is *one value*) in a list:

```
myList[startIndex:endIndex] = [newTuple]
```

Slice assignment always *iterates over the right-hand-side object*; you are replacing one list of indices with another.

From the assignment statement documentation:

> Finally, the sequence object is asked to replace the slice **with the items of the assigned sequence**. The length of the slice may be different from the length of the assigned sequence, thus changing the length of the target sequence, if the object allows it.

Since you provided a plain tuple, the elements from the tuple were used to replace the sliced indices. By wrapping it in a list, your tuple is one element in that list and is itself not further unpacked:

```
>>> myList = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5)]
>>> startIndex = 1
>>> endIndex = 3
>>> newTuple = (6,6)
>>> myList[startIndex:endIndex] = [newTuple]
>>> myList
[(1, 1), (6, 6), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> myList = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5)]
>>> myList[1:4] = [(6,6)]
>>> myList
[(1, 1), (6, 6), (5, 5)]
```